# String Header for data Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, header, numbers

I found "Adding a header to a matrix in Matlab" [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081721/adding-a-header-to-a-matrix-in-matlab) which was very close to what I need done. I was hoping to keep the data in the cells, since my headers are large and i'm running this multiple times I dont want to use file i.o. since it adds tons of time.

this is what i have...

- header = ( 'Quarter', 'monthly amount remaining', 'annual amountremaining');

  data   =

  ```
      1        30000    150000

      2        20000    130000
  ```

and i can't seem to get this

```
out = 

  Quarter    monthly am    annual am
        1         30000       150000

        2         20000      130000
```

It's very frustrating, i've tried num2str, and a bunch of other stuff... i'm going to try num2cell and just make a big array and fill them in... well happy friday, i'm heading home T_T

Comment: I don't understand.. are you trying to just get it to print output to the screen in the format you have there? Or do you want to write it to an xls or cvs file?

Comment: Iwas trying to avoid outputting into a file, we have alot of data moving around and without headers its impossible for me (the new guy) to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have access to the Statistics Toolbox, you can create a [dataset array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/dataset.html)

```
header = {'Quarter', 'monthly amount remaining', 'annual amountremaining'}
data =    [ 1        30000    150000;
    2        20000    130000];

ds = dataset({data,header{:}})

ds = 

    Quarter    monthlyAmountRemaining    annualAmountremaining
    1          30000                     1.5e+05              
    2          20000                     1.3e+05
```

Note that this removes the spaces in your header names, but with the dataset, you can then use these names to conveniently access the columns, such as:

```
>> ds.Quarter

ans =

     1
     2
```

If you just want to write to Excel (and not use the dataset methods), you can create a single cell array:

```
 [header;num2cell(data)]

ans = 

    'Quarter'    'monthly amount remaining'    'annual amountremaining'
    [      1]    [                   30000]    [                150000]
    [      2]    [                   20000]    [                130000]
```

Comment: Nice Jonas! Thats exactly what I wanted/needed!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware there is no true built in support for that.  Related to what Xurtio mentioned, you're wanting to do in reverse what Matlab undoes when it performs an xlsread.  Their solution is to create a matrix for the numbers (which have a fixed size and are therefore amenable to array style indexing), and a cell array for the strings which have a variable size.

The following is pretty much from the disp() Matlab docs and it accomplishes the effect, but not in a flexible way:

```
header='        Quarter  MonthlyAM   AnnualAM  ';
data=[1 30000 150000; 2 20000 130000];
disp(header);
disp(data);
    Quarter  MonthlyAM   AnnualAM  
       1       30000      150000
       2       20000      130000
```

If you want to achieve more flexible formatting, you could look into an sprintf intermediary for the data matrix.

Comment: i tried using disp to no avail... Prob my fault... also i was looking for the data in a structure (like the dataset soln above)... which I should have googled...