# Concatenate Cell Array of Headers with Matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix that looks like

```
  2          3         656
  6          2          4
  23         4          5
```

I also have an excel file that I imported into a cell array that looks like

```
Header1    Header2   Header3
```

How can I concatenate the headers so that I get a final table that looks like

```
Header1    Header2   Header3
  2          3         656
  6          2          4
  23         4          5
```

Thanks!

Comment: Unless I have misunderstood your question, trying this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268869/string-header-for-data-matlab.

Comment: @Abdou that only works if he has the statistics toolbox.  If you are trying to make a table, why can't you modify 'Table.Properties' shown here:  http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tableproperties.html ?

Comment: @brad so did you try my suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have access to the `table` function you can concatenate vertically the headers and your matrix, which you want to turn into a cell array:

```
M = {2          3         656
  6          2          4
  23         4          5}

Headers = {'Header 1' 'Header 2' 'Header 3'}

NewM = [Headers;M]
```

Now `NewM` looks like this:

```
NewM = 

    'Header 1'    'Header 2'    'Header 3'
    [       2]    [       3]    [     656]
    [       6]    [       2]    [       4]
    [      23]    [       4]    [       5]
```

Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: That's basically what I thought the OP wanted, but I didn't answer because it's too easy. +1.

Comment: haha yep I hesitated to make that a comment...maybe that's not what the OP wants lol