# MATLAB uint8 data type variable save

Tags: matlab, file-io, integer, save, text-files

does anyone know how to save an uint8 workspace variable to a txt file?
I tried using MATLAB save command:

```
save zipped.txt zipped -ascii
```

However, the command window displayed warning error:

> Warning: Attempt to write an unsupported data type to an ASCII file.
>       Variable 'zipped' not written to file.

Answer (score 1):

In order to write it, simply cast your values to double before writing it.

```
A=uint8([1 2 3])

toWrite=double(A)

save('test.txt','toWrite','-ASCII')
```

The reason uint8 can't be written is hidden in the format section of the save doc online, took myself a bit to find it.

The doc page is here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html

The 3rd line after the table in the format section (about halfway down the page) says:

> Each variable must be a two-dimensional double or character array.

**Alternatively**, dlmwrite can write matrices of type uint8, as the other poster also mentioned, and I am sure the csv one will work too, but I haven't tested it myself.

Hopefully that will help you out, kinda annoying though! I think uint8 is used almost exclusively for images in MATLAB, but I am assuming writing the values as an image is not feasible in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

have you considered other write-to-file options in Matlab?

How about [`dlmwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html)?
Another option might be [`cvswrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvwrite.html).

For more information see [this document](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/text-files.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
%# a random matrix of type uint8
x = randi(255, [100,3], 'uint8');

%# build format string
frmt = repmat('%u,',1,size(x,2));
frmt = [frmt(1:end-1) '\n'];

%# write matrix to file in one go
f = fopen('out.txt','wt');
fprintf(f, frmt, x');
fclose(f);
```

The resulting file will be something like:

```
16,108,149
174,25,138
11,153,222
19,121,68
...
```

where each line corresponds to a matrix row.

Note that this is [much faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6540984/97160) than using `dlmwrite` which writes one row at a time

Comment: I rolled back the suggested edit because it was incorrect. The `x'` was used to transpose the matrix `x`, and was not intended as a quoted string: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html

Comment: The reason for the transpose is that matrices in MATLAB are traversed in a [column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Column-major_order), but we wanted to write it to file row by row instead. In this case I was a bit lazy and should have used the [non-conjugate transpose](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) instead: `x.'` (here it doesn't really matter since the numbers are purely real)