# Missing something in the linux terminal after launching matlab from the command line

Tags: linux, bash, matlab

I'm having a weird behaviour when launching matlab from the command line in linux.

I've a bash script in linux that execute a function in matlab from the command line and does other operations with custom functions written in C++ as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
# prepare input data just to be sure it has not been written by other test!
matlab2011a -nodesktop -nosplash -r "prepare_data_matlab( 'A' ); quit"
# launch C++ program
...
# prepare more data
matlab2011a -nodesktop -nosplash -r "prepare_data_matlab( 'B' ); quit"
```

When the script is finished I can not see what I'm writing in the terminal, although the commands have effects. I need to `reset` the terminal.

The fact is that everything works fine if I only launch matlab with the `prepare_data_matlab( 'A' )` but the problem comes when I execute the function with option `prepare_data_matlab( 'B' )`.

I have commented line by line and found that the problem is with option `B` that call the function

```
dlmwrite(file_name, B, ' ');
```

which is not used in `prepare_data_matlab( 'A' )`.

So, how should I execute the matlab from the command line to avoid this behaviour? Is there a known bug with the `dlmwrite()` function?

I'm using *Ubuntu 12.04* 64 bits, GNU *bash*, versión *4.2.24(1)-release* (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) and *matlab2011a*.

**EDITED:** The output generated for `prepare_data_matlab( 'A' )` is
[image]

The output generated for `prepare_data_matlab( 'B' )` is
[image]

**EDITED:** `file_name` is created as `strcat(path_to_data,f);` where `path_to_data = /tmp/` and `f = data_out.txt`. Matrix `B` is not displayed before or after.

The only output to the terminal before or after the MATLAB script is generated from the bash script as follow:

```
echo "#### SELECT DATA FROM WORKSPACE ####"
matlab2011a -nodesktop -nosplash -r "prepare_data_matlab( 'B' ); quit";
echo "#### Process Data as input in a C++ programs ####"
```

The MATLAB function select data from the workscape and save it to disk as follows:

```
function [ ] = prepare_data_matlab( type )
if strcmp(type,'A')
    % load data from workscape
    load ('workspace_with_my_arrays.mat', 'A');    
    % save data as a standalone variable
    save('/tmp/A.mat', 'A');
elseif strcmp(type,'B')
    % load data from workscape
    load ('workspace_with_my_arrays.mat', 'B');    
    path_to_data = '/tmp/';
    f            = 'data_out.txt';
    file_name    = strcat(path_to_data,f);
    % save data as a txt file
    dlmwrite(file_name, B, ' ');
end
end
```

**EDITED:** whos -file workspace_with_my_arrays.mat

```
Name                             Size                     Bytes  Class     Attributes

A                             610x340x103            170897600  double              
B                             610x340x103            170897600  double
P                             610x340                  1659200  double              
t1                            38855x100                 31084000  double              
t2                            3921x2x100                6273600  double
```

There are more arrays in the workspace but those are which I load.

The `prepare_data_matlab` function is the same as posted above but with an argument error checking as follow:

```
%% Load data from file 
% Data is saved in a MATLAB variable or in TXT 
if nargin ~= 1
    error('Use: prepare_data_matlab( [ A | B ] )')
end
```

and the following command:

```
cd /data/matlab;
```

which is executed after the arguments error check in both cases (option `A`and option `B`), that is, before the `if` statement.

Comment: redirect the output to a file (shell redirection via `>`) and let us know what output is generated that corrupts the terminal.

Comment: @mnagel I have updated the question with the output generated by the matlab command. I did not notice about the strange characters and I have no idea what they mean.

Comment: Does the `"#### SELECT DATA FROM WORKSPACE ####"` message appear correctly on your screen?

Comment: @pQB: what is your goal here and what exactly is the problem? if you want to ignore any output from MATLAB to the standard output simply launch it as: `matlab ... > /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: @cabad Yes, the messages from the bash script appear correctly on the screen

Comment: @Amro The problem is that I do not see what I type in the console when the script finishes. In fact, if I run only the MATLAB script the same happens. The goal is to find what is wrong so I do not need type `reset` each time the script finishes.

Comment: To be as precise as possible, If I comment the line `dlmwrite(filename, B, ' ');` the problem disappears.

Comment: Are you sure that `filename` is correct? I still doubt that `dlmwrite` is the cause of the problem, but if it is you can replace it with `fprintf` with little effort. See here for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6540984/97160

Comment: @amro Yes, It's correct, I've checked it by opening when the script finishes (and removing it before it start :). I'll give a try to `fprintf`

Comment: this might be a better example for `fprintf`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17335675/97160

Comment: @amro Good point. I saved the data with fprintf as you suggested and the same happens (however is much faster :). Now I'm totally lost as dlmwrite is not the root of the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not with `dlmwrite`. This seems to be a bug in some versions of MATLAB, as reported in this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/288861).

The proposed solution (if you have a buggy version of MATLAB) is to use `nohup`:

```
nohup matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r ...........
```

**UPDATE:**
Per @Amro 's suggestion, @pQB reported the problem to MathWorks Support. Their response was:

> The problem is a known issue in versions prior to R2012a. Run MATLAB under a different shell. For example, neither tcsh or zsh have this issue.

**OLD answer:**
The problem is not with `dlmwrite`, but with the content of your matrix. Furthermore, unless `file_name` points to `stdout` (e.g., `file_name='/dev/stdout';`), the `dlmwrite` function will not write anything to screen and will not mess your terminal. Either `file_name` points to `stdout` or you are displaying the matrix B right before (or after) the `dlmwrite` call.

In any case, the problem is with the contents of your matrix B (see the strange characters in your output). You need to fix the problem with your matrix B. Perhaps the method you are using to read its input data is faulty.

Comment: Data is read from a MATLAB workscape. No output is written to the terminal from the MATLAB function before or after the `dlmwrite` call. I've updated the question with this information.

Comment: I changed my answer since I did some searching and found this to be a bug in MATLAB. As such, you cannot fix it, but you can get around it as suggested in my new answer.

Comment: You are right. Your suggestion solved the problem. So much error checking at all ...

Comment: huh, nice find +1. I would have never figured this out from my Windows machine :) This bug should be reported to MATLAB: http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/

Comment: @Amro From MathWork Support: The problem is a known issue in versions prior to R2012a. Run MATLAB under a different shell. For example, neither tcsh or zsh have this issue.

Comment: @pQB: I see, thanks for letting us know. cabad: you should add the reply from TMW to your answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore output from MATLAB (like the banner printed at the beginning), launch the process and redirect both the standard input and error to `/dev/null` device:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo '### running MATLAB ###'
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r "..." > /dev/null 2>&1
echo '### done ###'

./other_script.sh

matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r "..." > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Note that you should be careful since MATLAB process returns immediately possibly before it has finished running, which could cause problems if your next program depends on files produced by MATLAB. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4621554/97160) for a possible solution.

Comment: I tried redirect the output to the /dev/null and nothing is printed, neither the banner printed at the beginning. However, the problem persist. When the script finishes I do not see what I type in the linux console.

Comment: if you are not printing anything from MATLAB to the standard output, then perhaps its your C++ program that is corrupting the terminal?

Comment: I dont think so. I execute `matlab2011a -nodesktop -nosplash -r "prepare_data_matlab( 'B' ); quit";` from the linux bash terminal and the problem persists, but disappears if I comment the `dlmwrite` call within the prepare_data function.

Comment: is `prepare_data_matlab` exactly the same function posted in your question? also would help if you tell us what are the matrices `A` and `B`. Run `whos -file workspace_with_my_arrays.mat` and post the output please..

Comment: according to the above, A and B are multi-dimensional rather than 2D matrices. How do you want it to be written as ASCII file?

Comment: My apologies. I cleaned the next line -> `y = reshape( permute(B, [2 1 3]), size(B,1) * size(B,2), size(B,3));` before paste the code in the question (I simply renamed some variables and deleted extra comments)

Comment: Thank you for your effort but the problem is solved with the nohup answer. Especially thank for the fprintf suggestion :)