# Avoiding values to be written in engineering format in MATLAB while writing to csv

Tags: matlab, csv, file-io, precision

In MATLAB, I would like to write a matrix into a csv file using `dlmwrite`. The issue I am facing is that I would like all the numbers to be saved in the csv file in float (e.g. 0.0325 if it is float) or integer format (e.g. 12 if it is an integer), without them shown as engineering format:

I am trying it with :

```
      dlmwrite(filename,item_statistics_new,'-append','Precision','%g%g%g%g%g%g%g%g%g%1.8f');
```

and

```
     dlmwrite(filename,item_statistics_new,'-append','Precision','%1.8f');
```

or even

```
   dlmwrite(filename,item_statistics_new,'-append','Precision','%g');
```

Here is the output :

```
    24,4029,0.073663,0.00586759,3.6052,0.76092,0.0107733,2.86411,3,6.43734e-06
```

I am totally OK with all the columns (they are how I want) but I do not want the **last column** to be written in **engineering format** (6.43734e-06). The file will be passed into another program and having values in engineering format apparently is not supported.

The final columns of the matrix has got typically smaller values. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: You're probably better off using [`fprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html), I'm not sure that `dlmwrite` supports multiple precision strings.

Comment: I managed to do it with `fprintf`, thanks. The only drawback is that I could use `fprintf` in loop which was not something I intended to: `for m = 1 : size(movieIds14K,1)
     fprintf(fid,'%g,%g,%g,%g,%g,%g,%g,%g,%g,%1.8f \n',item_statistics_new(m,1)', item_statistics_new(m,2), item_statistics_new(m,3), item_statistics_new(m,4), ...
           item_statistics_new(m,5), item_statistics_new(m,6), item_statistics_new(m,7), item_statistics_new(m,8), ...
           item_statistics_new(m,9), item_statistics_new(m,10));
 end`

Comment: Might we be able to to write to csv rows of given matrix using `fprintf` in one line of code?

Comment: You shouldn't need to use a loop.

Comment: ok, given a matrix `M` (with size `p*q`) where `p` is huge and `q=10`, how could we write the rows into a csv file using `fprintf`, please? Ideas are apprecited.

Comment: Have you tried someting like `fprintf(fid,<identifiers>,item_statistics_new(:,:))`?

Comment: Read the documentation, [there are examples](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html#btf98f7) that are similar to what you need.

Comment: Crowly, your approach does NOT print the columns in order.

Comment: @Yas see here for an example of how to write matrix to CSV in one fprintf call: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6540984/97160